# socket.io client not connecting to server

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

Here is the server code

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const {Subject, merge} = require('rxjs')
const {filter, throttleTime} = require('rxjs/operators')
const {ENABLE_CHAR} = require('./constants')
const log = require('./log')


module.exports = ({port, ssl}) => {
    const app = express()

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')))    
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.html')
    })

    const send$ = new Subject()    
    const sslCredentials = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(ssl.key || __dirname + '/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(ssl.cert || __dirname + '/cert.pem')
    }
    
    const server = https.createServer(sslCredentials, app)    
      
   
      
    const socket = require("socket.io")(server,{
        pingInterval: 1000,
        pingTimeout: 5000,
    })
    
  
    socket.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('user connected ipaddress' + client.connection.remoteAddress )
        socket.on('join', function(userNickname) {
        console.log(userNickname +" : has logged in "  )                           
    });
}); 
server.listen(port, () => {
    log.info(`Server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

Android app code

```java
package com.example.accentag4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Socket mSocket;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mSocket = IO.socket("https://alfred.local:883");
            mSocket.connect();
            mSocket.emit("join", "superman");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            alert.setTitle("AlertDialogExample");
            alert.show();
        }

    }
}
```

The event join never fires because I dont receive the message on the console